# What is the difference between a random variable and a random vector?

Tags: probability, random-variables

In probability, I know that a random variable is a variable whose value is unknown, ie it is a function that assigns values to each of an experiment's outcomes. But recently I came across the term a 'random vector' in the phrase 'Gaussian random vectors'. Is a random vector simply a random variable that exists in multiple dimensions? If not, what is it?

Comment: "variable whose value is unknown" - is strange definition: we know as values, so probability distribution.

Answer (score 0):

A random variable $X:\Omega\to S$ is a measurable function mapping from a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ into a measure space $(S,\mathcal{S})$. If $S$ is a vector space (usually $S=\mathbb{R}^d$), one says that $X$ is a random vector ($X(\omega)$ is a vector in $S$).